# C# app config database variables

Tags: c#, app-config

Ok I am kind of having some issue here. I was wondering what would work for my app config in my case. This is my code:

```
name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
size = e.Name.Length;
strSelectCmd = "INSERT INTO" + tablemysql + " ("+column1+","+column2+","+column3+","+column4+") VALUES('" + name + "','" + size + "',now(),'" + extension + "')";
```

Now I want the value of the variables: `name` `size` and `extension` to be adjustable. I was thinking of some ways to do this.
Like putting this in the app config:

```
<add key="value1" value="e.Name.Length"/>
```

This probably wont work.

What would I have to do if I want for example `size` to be adjustable. So when someone uses a different kind of column in the database(like they change `size` in their database to `user` , they can change the name/value of the so called: `size` as well?

There might be a very simple solution to this, if so, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `name` and `size` are the values, you would rather get `column1` and `column2` et.c. from application settings if you want to have the field names configurable:

```
column1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"];
```

Only concatenate the table name and field names into the string. Use parameters for the values. Your implementation was wide open for SQL injection attacks.

```
strSelectCmd = "INSERT INTO `" + tablemysql + "` (`"+column1+"`,`"+column2+"`,`"+column3+"`,`"+column4+"`) VALUES(@name,@size,@time,@extension)";
```

Use backticks around the identifiers, so that the code doesn't break if someone uses an SQL keyword as an identifier.

(I'm assuming from the variable name `tablemysql` that you are using MySQL as database.)

#### Edit:

To have configurable values, you would need to set up a way to specify a range of different values using strings. You can create a dictionary with the avialable values:

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
values.Add("name", name);
values.Add("size", size);
values.Add("time", time);
values.Add("extension", extension);
values.Add("user", user);
```

You can get strings from the settings and use to get the corresponding value:

```
object value1 = values[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["value1"]];
object value2 = values[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["value2"]];
object value3 = values[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["value3"]];
object value4 = values[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["value4"]];
```

The query would specify parameters for the values:

```
strSelectCmd = "INSERT INTO `" + tablemysql + "` (`"+column1+"`,`"+column2+"`,`"+column3+"`,`"+column4+"`) VALUES(@value1,@value2,@value3,@value4)";
```

Now you can use those variables when you create the parameter objects to use with the query. Example:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@value1", value1));
```

Comment: Column1 and column2 are just the column names which I already got in the app config. Name and size etc are the values. How do I get those in the appconfig? And yes I am using mysql.

Comment: @loko: I see. To have configurable values you need to set up a range of possible values identifiable by strings. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Putting these into the configuration file is a valid option. For simplicity, you could use the [AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this (see your XML excerpt). 
You can access AppSettings by using [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
size = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["size"] ? e.Name.Length : int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["size"];
```

In order to use ConfigurationManager, you might need to add a reference to the System.Configuration assembly.

Answer (score 0):

lets do it in 2 steps. 1st: declare the columnKey in configuration and read from there

```
column2 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["columnKey"];
```

2nd: Read value based on key

```
string size = GetSizeValue(column2, e);
```

GetSizeValue will look something like this:

```
private static string GetSizeValue(string columnKeyValue, SomeArgsType e)
    {
        switch (columnKeyValue)
        {
            case "size":
                return e.Name.Length;
            case "user":
                return e.Name.User; // or something else
        }

        throw new Exception("Invalid Entry");
    }
```